# Pickled Matplotlib figure object- retrieving data

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle

I am trying to save a figure object as a pickle file and retrieve the data from it later. I practiced on a sample code but I am unable to retrieve the data from the pickle file after loading it. Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

Fs = 8000
f = 1000
sample =20000
x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('voltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('sample(n)')
plt.show()

dt=1.0/Fs
winsize=1024
shift=int(winsize/2)
frqlen=shift
datalen=len(y)
FFTdata=np.zeros((0,frqlen))
fftfreq=np.fft.fftfreq(winsize,d=dt)[:frqlen]
for i in range(0,datalen,shift):
 xdata=x[i:i+winsize]
 if len(xdata)!=winsize:
   break
 fftdata=np.fft.fft(xdata,winsize)
 absdata=np.abs(fftdata)[:frqlen]
 logpower=10* np.log(absdata ** 2).reshape((1,len(absdata)))
 FFTdata=np.append(FFTdata,logpower,axis=0)
sampleno=np.arange(1,len(FFTdata)+1)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
FFTdata=FFTdata.T
im=ax.pcolor(sampleno,fftfreq,FFTdata)
cbar=fig.colorbar(im)
fig.show()

pickle.dump(fig,open("dumptrial.p",'wb'))

figure=pickle.load(open("dumptrial.p",'rb'))
figure.show()
data=figure.axes[0].images[0].get_data()
```

On the last line `data=figure.axes[0].images[0].get_data()` python throws an `Indexing error: List index out of range`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-e9dc466f2abb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/na.anusuya/Documents/pickletrial.py', wdir='C:/Users/na.anusuya/Documents')

  File "C:\Users\na.anusuya\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\na.anusuya\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/na.anusuya/Documents/pickletrial.py", line 43, in <module>
    data=figure.axes[0].images[0].get_data()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please help me how to retrieve data from pickled figure object?

(The source I used for this code is: https://gist.github.com/demisjohn/883295cdba36acbb71e4
http://fredborg-braedstrup.dk/blog/2014/10/10/saving-mpl-figures-using-pickle/
)

Comment: Please add appropriate indentation to your code. Also, what is the operation you meant to test in your if condition `if len(xdata)<>winsize:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with pickling.
Just `figure.axes[0].images` is zero-length.

pcolor returns a PolyCollection ([matplotlib page)](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html)

You can see that there is a PolyCollection by running

```
print(figure.axes[0].get_children())
```

Now you can access the object by

```
pycol = None
for obj in figure.axes[0].get_children():
    if isinstance(obj, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection):
        pycol = obj
        break
print(pycol)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what is going on when I do `pickle.load(file)`. Thank you very much for taking the time.